# Show Custom Error page if SQL Connection is not established (The underlying provider failed on Open happens)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, connection-string

I followed the instruction as mentioned in [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/24395wz3(v=vs.100)) to prevent yellow page if connection string is not established like code below:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the exception object.
        Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();//Gives Error Correctly
        Response.Redirect("~/Errors/404.htm");//Reponse Is Null!!
        Server.ClearError();
    }
```

but within "Application_Error" method it raises an error which says "Response is not available in this context"!. therefor it is not possible to redirect to my error page.

Any suggestions please?